# How to create queue in service bus in azure by application

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

Is it possible to create a queue on the azure service bus by the sdk?

Same as RabbitMQ

```
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "" ....
```

Comment: Targets track 1 ASB SDK but the concept is the same: [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/automatic-queue-creation-for-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` and its [`CreateQueueAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.createqueueasync?view=azure-dotnet).

> Creates a new queue in the service namespace with the given name.

```
var administrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient("ServiceBusConnectionString");
await administrationClient.CreateQueueAsync(queueName);
```

Make sure the connection string has manage rights.

*Updated to target the current generation of packages thanks to Jesse Squire's comment below*

Comment: This is correct for the legacy `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` package.  In the current generation, `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`, you'd use `ServiceBusAdministrationClient`   _([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.createqueueasync?view=azure-dotnet))_    For new development, we recommend using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JesseSquire, missed the new `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` there. Answer has been updated.

Comment: @jesse Squir using ServiceBusAdministrationClient do I need to close connection or dispose?
ManagementClient contained CloseAsync.

Comment: No, you do not.   Since administration is performed via HTTP-based service calls, the admin client does not need to be explicitly closed.   It follows the lifetime guidance discussed in "[Lifetime management for Azure SDK .NET clients](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/lifetime-management-and-thread-safety-guarantees-of-azure-sdk-net-clients/)".    _(note that the other Service Bus clients do need to be explicitly closed/disposed due to their use of persistent AMQP connections)_